# Python - get index of character in list

Tags: python, list

This here works and returns the index:

```
>>> ['a', 'b'].index('b')
1
```

However, this will not return the index,.

```
>>> ['a', 'bbc'].index('b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    ['a', 'bb'].index('b')
ValueError: 'b' is not in list
>>>
```

How can I find the index just by a single character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to find all:

```
[i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if 'b' in val]
```

or `next()` with a generator expression to find the first:

```
next(i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if 'b' in val)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'bbc']
>>> [i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if 'b' in val]
[1]
>>> next(i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if 'b' in val)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all the positions of `'b'` in all the strings:

```
In [100]: lst = ['a', 'bbc']

In [101]: [[i for i,char in enumerate(s) if char=='b'] for s in lst]
Out[101]: [[], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: suggest: `[[i for i,char in enumerate(substr) if char=='b'] for s in lst if 'b' in s]` There is no need for the second `enumerate` and if you test for the character in the string `s` you won't get empty lists...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going with Martijn's answer.

That said, here's an [*itertools*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) version just for fun:

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> from itertools import compress, count, imap
>>> s = ['a', 'bbc', 'def', 'gbh', 'ijk']
>>> list(compress(count(), imap(methodcaller('__contains__', 'b'), s)))
[1, 3]
```

This shows a typical pattern for using [*compress*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress).  The core idea is to create a stream of True and False values based on some condition (i.e. the presence of `b`) and to use those values to select elements from another data stream (i.e. the indicies of the matches).

This technique is very old and has its roots in languages such as [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))